# How to refer to an entry in Index / Glossaries?

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, indexing, makeindex

I want to refer to some important keywords (defined by Index) and concepts (defined by glossary) in text.Suppose I've created `[[Prototype]]` as Index at some place and  `class` and `inheritance` as glossary at other places.

My question is how can I reference them so that the text displayed here is something like:

pseudo latex code:

```
In Chapter 5, we addressed the \ref{index:Prototype} mechanism in
detail, and why it's confusing and inappropriate to describe it as
\ref{glossary:class} or \ref{glossary:inheritance} ...
```

desired output:

```
In Chapter 5, we addressed the [[Prototype]](§1.2.3 page 123)
mechanism in detail, and why it's confusing and inappropriate to
describe it as class (Glossary page 234) or inheritance (Glossary
page 235) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `entrycounter` package option creates a counter that's automatically incremented using `\refstepcounter` when the top-level entries are listed in the glossary. By default this will also display the counter value in front of the entry, but this can be changed by redefining `\glsentrycounterlabel` to do nothing. The argument of `\label` is formed from `glsentry-`*tag* where *tag* is the entry's label.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[entrycounter]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\renewcommand{\glsentrycounterlabel}{}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample} described on page \pageref{glsentry-sample}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer! However, would you please tell me how to deal with Index? Many thanks!

Comment: @spacegoing If you're just using `glossaries.sty`'s `index` package option and `\newterm`, it's just the same. If you mean using a package like `makeidx` or `imakeidx` then that would require a different method, and you'll have to post it as a separate question.